# Need to extract/consolidate info from database files

Tags: database, excel, spreadsheet

Here's a summary of my problem:

- Our company's old software had a large database of contacts in it.
- We switched to a new program and have no way to easily transfer those contacts to it.
- The contacts database appears to have 4 files which can all be opened in Excel, but not MSAccess. The four files contain the following:

File 1: A nicely formatted spreadsheet of names and some other BASIC info for each contact. There is an ID number on each one, but the numbers do not seem to correspond to anything in File 2.

File 2: Info on each contact, but not in rows. Instead it looks something like this :

```
JHGH_CONTACT_BLOB: 1426367745               
EMAIL: SMITH                
WEB:                
PHONE_COUNT: 1              
FAX_COUNT: 0                
ADDRESS_COUNT: 0                
NOTE_COUNT: 0               

555-7364
```

(I changed some info for privacy reasons)

Each blob of info is on a separate spreadsheet row. Each starts off with the same first line, even the number is the same, so it can't be some sort of ID number.

File 3: A file containing a lot of gobbledygook, interspersed with a few readable bits of text here and there. The readable text looks like it belongs to the database (ie, it is info on contacts like place of work and other notes.)

File 4: Contains one row and one column labeled ID, with the number 12725 in it.

I need to somehow get the info from File 2, into the nicely formatted file 1. In essence, I need to add the phone numbers, emails etc included in a messy fashion in file 2 on their proper rows in file 1.

This probably makes little sense and I thank you for even reading down this far. If you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Thanks

Comment: Was the old system based on off-the-shelf software or was it a totally custom solution?

Comment: It was a piece of software specific to my industry.  It was not as off-the-shelf as MS Office, but it also wasn't made just for us -- although I'm told the company that makes it is very small.

Comment: That makes it less likely that the files will be in any format which Excel could be made to read. Do any of the files have extensions which might give us a clue? E.g. .xls would obviously be an Excel file. I think file 3 would be the most useful one to find out more about if possible

Comment: The files are: File 1: contacts.dbf (nicely formatted, 2MB), File 2: contacts.fpt (blobs of info, 6MB) and File 3: contacts.cdx (gobbledygook 1.5MB).

Comment: dbf is almost certainly going to be a dBase file and Excel can open those. Go File menu > Open then click on the arrow next to "Files of type" and scroll down the list until you find "dBase files (*.dbf)". .fpt and .cdx should both be Visual FoxPro files

Answer (score 0):

We have established that you have a DBF file, an FPT file and a CDX file. These are likely to all relate to Visual FoxPro (a now discontinued Microsoft product).

The .dbf file can be opened in Excel via the standard file open dialog by changing "Files of type" to "dBase files (*.dbf)". Going by your original post, Excel seems to be able to open this sensibly in the first place.

The combination of all three files might be accessible by downloading [this OLE DB provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=E1A87D8F-2D58-491F-A0FA-95A3289C5FD4&displaylang=en) for FoxPro which would let you access the database from Excel using the methods outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e5x014a%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

You can get more info on the specific file structures at the following links: [DBF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st4a0s68%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), [FPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8599s21w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [CDX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k35b9hs2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). The DBF contains most of the data, the FPT contains binary memo data and the CDX is an index file.